# Error saving credentials: error storing credentials Timeout was reached

Tags: linux, heroku, containers

When working with Heroku, I tried to get access to the container registry with the following command:

```
heroku login
sudo heroku container:login
```

After some seconds, I receive the following message:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials -err: exit status 1, 
out: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached
```

What am I missing? I am running this command under my Linux Mint 19 dist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to install the following:

```
sudo apt install gnupg2 pass
```