# Git Credentials Libsecret: Error calling StartServiceByName, Timeout was reached

Tags: git, archlinux

I've been using libsecret for git credentials for a time now.  However, I had to do a reinstall of my ArchLinux, and now, the following error is returned after I try to do any operation with git...

```
** (process:1624): CRITICAL **: 22:19:02.245: could not connect to Secret Service: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?  The following is my git config:

```
credential.helper=/usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-libsecret
```

Comment: I'd poke around in the config files for systemd: the failure to start the service *by name* suggests that maybe the name doesn't exist there. Check the Arch Linux systemd documentation to find locations, as they move around from one Linux to another and I don't have them memorized.

Comment: I just realized that I'm starting ```gnome-keyring-daemon``` from my ```.zlogin``` file.  Could you please elaborate more, I got a bit lost here...

Comment: I'm not sure what a `.zlogin` file *is* (zsh login? I don't use zsh myself).

Comment: ```.zlogin``` is a file used to setup the Zsh login shell.

Comment: This is what I get from the journal:  https://pastebin.com/93nVj5wP

Answer (score 0):

Check first if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58533737/6309), there is a component you need to install, like [pass](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pass):

```
pasman -S gnu2 pass
```

If you are using GNOME, see "[GNOME/Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Using_the_keyring)", and make sure **[`libsecret`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=libsecret)** is installed (and double-check the [`/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon` setuid bit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-keyring-list/2014-June/msg00001.html)).

Comment: I installed both, but still have the same problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Why do I need to look for GNOME/Keyring if I'm using libsecret?  I have libsecret installed and gnome-keyring-daemon do not have the setuid bit set.

Comment: If I do ```systemctl status``` the following is outputed:  ```/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11```

Comment: I came to realize that I'm starting ```gnome-keyring-daemon``` from my ```.zlogin``` file...

Comment: @Procer.Scvtvlatvs As in https://git.bracken.jp/dotfiles/commit/e3a9a2de85a21d55c7a70563b549ab065ee6266c.html#h0 ? Did you export the output of `gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg`?

Comment: I exported the output just like your link shows and now ```systemctl status``` outputs: ```gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets```.  I tried to do a ```git pull``` but it returns the timeout error again.

Comment: If I run the command from Zsh the following output is returned:  ```** Message: 21:12:55.491: couldn't access control socket: /home/user/.xdg/runtime/keyring/control: No such file or directory```.  Then It returns the following: ```SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/user/.xdg/runtime/keyring/ssh```

Comment: @Procer.Scvtvlatvs See if, as in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224652, you are missing a `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY`, after the `eval` and `export` commands. But check first if your .xinitrc is properly setup: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#xinitrc (which would make that dbus command unneeded)

Comment: I tried running that command manually from my shell (Zsh) but the following error was returned: ```dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1 ```. The following paste displays my ```.xinitrc``` file:  https://pastebin.com/ff8gD4f3

Comment: The journal (```journalctl -t dbus-daemon```) returns me this:  https://pastebin.com/93nVj5wP

Comment: What does your service file includes? (as in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5247#issuecomment-762250216)

Comment: Exactly the same as the link you just pasted.

Comment: And what is your dbus version? (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/b895fa08e6809ab54e20888f7d01ae848272e981#diff-350001c5bb6582c2bad399a5ec4f9f85362a9963d5696394ca897d77d9c34103)

Comment: I don't know.  How can I get to know it?

Comment: @Procer.Scvtvlatvs Not sure. May be one of the tools/links listed in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/D-Bus will give a clue.